# Date and time resets to 1970 after every shutdown

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-droid-razr, date-and-time

I'm having trouble with date and time on my Droid Razr M running Android 4.4.2. Every time my phone shuts off it goes back to 1970 and I can't get on the internet or any of my apps.